# Get post-data that is in the same query as checkbox

Tags: php, forms

Well, it's a little hard to explain...

I'll just post my code and say what I want.

I have this in my form (relevant code):

```
echo ("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"cid[]\" value=\"".$row['cid']."\" />");  
echo ("<textarea name=\"bericht[]\">".$row['bericht']."</textarea>");
echo ("<input type=\"submit\" name=\"bewerkenSubmit\" value=\" Bewerken \" />");
```

And this in the validator:

```
if(isset($_POST['bewerkenSubmit'])) 
{
    $cid = $_POST['cid'];
    $bericht = $_POST['bericht'];



    if(empty($cid)) 
    {
        echo("<p>No comments selected.</p>\n");
    } 
    else 
    {
        $N = count($cid);
        for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
        {
            mysql_query("UPDATE comments SET bericht='$bericht_id[$i]' WHERE cid='$cid[$i]'");
            echo ("Cid: $cid[$i]<br />"); 
            echo ("Bericht: $bericht[$i]<br />"); // THIS IS THE PART THAT DOESN'T WORK.. it only displays the first option of 'bericht'...
            header("Location:".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?onderdeel=blog&action=reacties&bid=".$bid);
        }
        echo("</p>");
    }

}
```

It basically should check what checkbox has been checked (which works already), and update the textarea _POST information into the database (which doesn't work).

I am a beginner in PHP and don't really understand how for() works, too.. :P

EDIT: http://dhost.info/ddfs/myproblem.html I uploaded the whole script. I hope you can see what it should do. I added

```
<!-- RELEVANT CODE -->
```

so you can see what is important.

The highslide div is for the textarea. I hid it, because that looks prettier.
Just so you know: the whole code works as it should, no bugs really. It is only the 'bewerken' (= edit in Dutch) part.

Answer (score 1):

In your update statement try changing

```
SET bericht='$bericht_id[$i]' WHERE
```

to

```
SET bericht='$bericht[$i]' WHERE
```

As for how for() works.. think of it as a condensed while() for example:

```
$i = 0;
while($i < 10)
{
    echo 'Number '.$i;
    $i++;
}
```

Could be condensed using a for() loop:

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
    echo 'Number '.$i;
}
```

A for() loop means keep looping by doing part 3 ($i++), until part 2 is no longer true ($i < 10) - start the loop at part 1 ($i = 0). This means that in my example, it is starting with $i equal to 0, incrementing by one on each loop ($i++) until $i is greater than or equal to 10.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. :)
However, what I really meant was: how to implement the bericht[] also in the for() statement, so it will update the right 'bericht' for the 'cid'?

I could post the whole code if you want, so you can see more of its context..

Comment: No problem, the line "UPDATE comments SET bericht='$bericht[$i]' WHERE cid='$cid[$i]'" is already updating the `bericht` field to $bericht[$i] where the `cid` field is $cid[$i]. Is this not what you're after?

Comment: Well, that's what I thought, too. However, it's not working. :(
I think it updates the first and the last one..

Edited first post.

Comment: Is $bericht returning wrong data or no data? - By the way in the code you posted you are using square brackets [] instead of <> for your textarea tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to remove your array-style variables from the string, and properly escape the textarea contents.  Try this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE comments SET bericht='" . mysql_real_escape_string($bericht[$i]) . "' WHERE cid='" . $cid[$i] . "'");
```

and

```
echo ("Bericht: " . $bericht[$i] . "<br />");
```

The variable was also typo'd in the update statement..

Comment: yeah you got nice suggestions... too

Comment: Well, you are right, but that doesn't change anything in the output. @ the escape_string: I already had this: 
    $bericht = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bericht']);

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

$bericht is returning wrong data. It either gives the information of the first row, or the last row.
@ brackets around textarea: I know.. That was for the big textarea, so it wouldn't be closed.

EDIT: Little update: if I select all the rows, it works just fine. However, I need the user to be able to de-select one row from editing.
If I select just one row, it always takes the first $bericht[$i]..